# transfering database between python and sqlite3 cli tool

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I need a way to access a database created in my python3 application in memory (':memory:') in the command line interface tool sqlite3. The idea is to provide the user with the convenience of the standard sqlite3 tool instead of reimplementing a sqlite shell in python itself.

Again, the goal is:

Database opened in my python program in memory -> editing/processing the database in sqlite3 cli tool --> moving the (potentially) modified database back to my python program.

What I tried to to:

```
def sqlite_cli(self):
    # Spawn the original sqlite3 cli interface
    # Dump the database in a named temporary file. Read it back into
    # memory. At close() the tempfile will be erased.
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as tf:
        for line in self.connection.iterdump():
            tf.write(bytes(line, 'ascii'))

        # Work with the database through sqlite3
        subprocess.call(['sqlite3', '-init', tf.name])

        # Read the potentially modified database
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        # Here happens the logic gap: The sqlite3 tool doesn't 
        # save modifications to the file opend as the -init argument.
        # How can I save the modifications done within sqlite3 as a 
        # sql text file ready to be read back into the app?!
        tf.seek(0)
        edited_db = tf.read()

        # Delete all tables residing in memory
        try:
            for t in ACCMAN_TABLES:
                self.cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s' % t)
            self.connection.commit()
            # Add the (maybe) edited one
            self.cursor.executescript(edited_db.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
            self.connection.commit()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            logger.error("sqlite_cli(): %s" % e.args[0])

        tf.close()
```

In this case, **I need a way to save all modifications done on the database opened with *sqlite -init filename* either in a sql or binary (the normal one...) format on the filesystem.**

Edit: One solution would be to let the user do his stuff on the database and then before he ends the session (capturing  stdin for .q .quit .exit), I could send an intermediary

```
.output outfile.sql
.dump
.quit
```

to redirect the whole database (and it's modifications!) on the filesystem and then read the created file back into the python app. But this is so ugly and unelegant...

Comment: Why are you keeping the database in memory? Wouldn't it be easier to just open it in a temporary file to begin with, and have both Python and `sqlite3` alternately work with that same file?

Comment: Because there shouldn't be any files beside the script itself. The applications purpose is to extract the database (aes encrypted and base64 encoded) from the script file itself and read it into memory. The information in the database is highly sensitive and shouldn't be saved on the filesystem.

Comment: Your suggestion to dump the DB into a SQL file is confusing in that case. Same for using `NamedTemporaryFile` in your first proposed solution. Both have the exact same security implications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to like this answer, but I'd consider writing the "model" in your app as a "server" capable of receiving xml-rpc calls.  This way, your "controller" (as well as external controllers) can hit the database and do whatever you allow them to do. It's pretty easy to expose methods of a class as an XML-RPC server.  See http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html?highlight=xmlrpc#xmlrpclib